# Calling a JS class from a script tag

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class declared in a script imported before body:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var FamilleTree = function() {
  };
  FamilleTree.prototype.someAlert=function() {
    alert("test");
  }
});
```

After that, I have the following code inside the body in a script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var famtree= new FamilleTree();
    famtree.someAlert();
});
```

But when I load the page, here is the error from firefox:

```
ReferenceError: FamilleTree is not defined
```

The class is defined before the call, why is it not accessible ?

Comment: Need HTML and maybe CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: It is not a duplicate, my problem was with document ready. And i have edited the original problem to be easily reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FamilleTree's scope is limited to the closure (the function inside document.ready). When you call from the other function the variable isn't in scope anymore. Try declaring FamilleTree outside the $(document).ready like this:

```
var FamilleTree = function(tree) {
  this.tree=tree
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  FamilleTree.prototype.drawTree=function() {
    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: this.tree,
        dragAndDrop: true
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what was blocking me !